# Как избавиться от отображения квадратиков вместо иконок в приложении?

Tags: android-studio, icon, mipmaps

Вместо иконок в моём приложении на экранах с размерами меньше чем 480 x 854 px отображаются квадратики. **Выглядит это так:**

[image: Телефон: 3.4" WQVGA API-23; 240x432px; ldpi]

Телефон: 3.4" WQVGA API-23; 240x432px; ldpi.

[image: Телефон: 3.3" WQVGA API-23; 240x400px; ldpi]

Телефон: 3.3" WQVGA API-23; 240x400px; ldpi.

[image: Телефон: 2.7" QVGA API-23; 240x320; ldpi]

Телефон: 2.7" QVGA API-23; 240x320; ldpi.

**А должно выглядеть так:**

[image: Телефон: 3.2" HVGA slider ADP1 API-23; 320x480px; mdpi]

Телефон: 3.2" HVGA slider ADP1 API-23; 320x480px; mdpi.

**Или так:**

[image: Телефон: 5.4" FWVGA API-27; 480x854; mdpi]

Телефон: 5.4" FWVGA API-27; 480x854; mdpi.

Так выглядит шаблон меню в студии:

[image: Шаблон меню в студии]

**Внимание вопрос! Как избавиться от отображения квадратиков вместо иконок?**

---

Загадочным образом все иконки в папке ...\res\mipmap-ldpi оказались с белым фоном, а нужен - прозрачный.

Comment: для начала переместить иконки из папки `/mipmap` в папку `/drawable` с соответствующими квалификаторами

Comment: Вас уже должно было насторожить, что ваши mipmap-ы не показываются, а кнопка "еще" из папки /drawable - видна на всех скриншотах. Mipmap вообще используется для иконки приложения, а не иконок в приложении

Comment: Причина была в том, что для всех типов экранов, кроме ldpi, использовались иконки с прозрачным фоном.